# Error: not enough space for card marking array

Tags: java, memory

Basically, my problem is that my Java throws errors if I try to reserve more than 512M heap space, even though I have about 1,7GB of RAM free on my 2GB RAM virtual server.

I'll explain it using bash. I'd like to reserve about 1024M of RAM for my Minecraft server, which worked about 3 or 4 days ago, but after server problems of our hoster it stopped working. I'm still in contact with the hoster, but they take time to answer at the moment.

I'm using java -version in this example:

```
root@v0057:~# java -Xmx1024M -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for the card marking array
```

However, when I do this, it works:

```
root@v0057:~# java -Xmx512M -version
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

Same goes for launching it without `-Xmx`.

I already tried reinstalling the virtual server and java, upgrading my Java from 6 to 7 and starting the java process with only the system processes running. I would appreciate any help right now.

The Server is running on Debian Squeeze.

Comment: I forgot to add, the server is running on Debian Squeeze.

Answer (score 2):

Well -Xmx sets maximum heap size. You need to remember that apart from heap there is also PermGen (and *many* other things). You also need to remember that the java process itself will use some RAM. Even though you have ~1.7GB free and you set -Xmx to "only" 1GB doesn't mean that you will actually have that much RAM free since all the aforementioned things also will consume some (and there are JVM/OS specific things like does the OS need continuous chunks of memory to allocate objects, does the JVM start with -Xmx right of the bat when no -Xms is present etc. though on Debian all of this should not be a problem).

You can try running java in client mode (funny enough modern personal computers are good enough for java to run as servers by default):

```
java -client -Xmx1024M
```

Or you can try lowering the `-XX:MaxPermSize` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the easy understandable explanation. (: I tried various combinations of your tips, but I still get the same error. I'll try running it with 512M for now and wait for my hoster to answer, since I feel like it's something they changed, at least if nobody else has a working idea.